# Ajax.Updater output garbled only on iPhone first load

Tags: iphone, ajax, character-encoding, prototypejs

When a user loads my page for the first time on an iPhone (works fine on Android, IE, FF,
Opera, Chrome, Safari), the two portions of the page generated by a Prototype/Scriptaculous Ajax.Updater call are garbled - they look as if a binary file were injected into the page or the character map was scrambled. If the user then reloads the page, or uses the page's tabs to navigate around via Ajax.Updater requests, everything is then fine. It's only the very first time the page is loaded in a browser session that this occurs. Here are the relevant calls with a bit of context:

```
soundManager.onready(function(){
    new Ajax.Updater('PlayerSet', 'http://' + location.host +
        playerHTMLloc, {method: 'post', onComplete: startPlayer});
});
```

This is only called once per site visit (so the user has to reload in order to get it to display correctly). It calls a python script that writes html to stdout.

Here's the other:

```
show: function(elm) {
    var id = elm.identify();
    elm.addClassName(id.sub('-html', '-selected'));
    var link = 'ajax/' + id.sub('-', '.');
    $('centercontent').update('<div id="floaterForSpinner"></div><div
          id="centerSpinner"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>');
    new Ajax.Updater('centercontent', link, {evalScripts: 'true',
        method: 'post'});
}
```

This is part of a small class that handles tabs on the page. Again, only the first time show() is called does the error occur. After that the tabber works normally. The updater is just pulling html text files from the server.

The issue occurs with both Prototype/Scripty 1.6.1/1.8.3 and 1.7/1.9.0.

The post and receive headers are identical for the first and subsequent loads, and the acceptable charset is `Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7` in all cases per Firebug.

I don't have an iPhone myself, and none of the off or online iPhone simulators I've tried reproduce the problem, so testing this is going to be a nightmare. Hence, anything anyone could do to help, would be, uh, very... helpful.

**UPDATE** based on questions I received on the GG prototype list:

All the code above is called after the DOM is loaded:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        Ajax.Responders.register({onCreate: removeListeners});
        Ajax.Responders.register({onComplete: postAJAX});
        new Lightbox();
        initMailList();
        AT = new AjaxTabber('tablist');
        initInternalLinkListener();
        initIE6msgClose();
        $('PlayerSet').update('<div style="text-align:center">
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>');
        soundManager.onready(function(){
            new Ajax.Updater('PlayerSet', 'http://' + location.host +
                 playerHTMLloc, {method: 'post', onComplete: startPlayer});
        });
});
```

AjaxTabber is the tab class that contains the show() function I mentioned earlier. The document.observe function above is in the last js file in the header.

**UPDATE #2:**

Replacing

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
```

with

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
```

in the 3rd code block fixes the garbled loads. However, the fix raises new questions/issues:

1. Why do the Ajax.Updater loads need to have the entire page loaded to work correctly? A DOM load should be all that's necessary. There's no reason to need the images loaded for an ajax load to work.
2. My overall page performance is now substantially degraded to fix an iPhone only problem. I'd really like to go back to loading once the DOM load is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Calling update() and then Ajax.Updater on the same element one after another like this might introduce timing problems that can be difficult to diagnose. I recommend doing this instead (to add a "loading" indicator to your Ajax-loading element):

```
new Ajax.Updater('elementID', '/path/to/server', {
  parameters: {}, 
  method: 'get',
  onCreate: function(){
    $('elementID').update('placeholder html here');
  },
  onSuccess: function(){
    // any other cleanup here
  }
});
```

The onCreate callback hook will guarantee to run *and complete* before the request is sent and the element is updated by A.U.

Comment: Hi Walter, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the question is almost 2 years old and the webpage in question is long gone so I can't test your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I had a bit of a face-palm when I looked at the date.